# Spring boot yaml property boolean not recognized

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following in application.yml:

```
perscel:
  mail:
    featuretoggle: true
```

Following field:

```
@Value("${perscel.mail.featuretoggle}")
private final Boolean isFeatureActive;
```

results in:

> Parameter 7 of constructor in be.cm.apps.press.perscel3.cron.CronJob
> required a bean of type 'java.lang.Boolean' that could not be found.

A bit annoyed by the unexpected issue, clearly the boolean field is set to true.
Note that all other fields under the same namespaces are properly filled in, it is literally only the boolean field that is causing the problem.
I have no additional configuration for reading properties files.

Spring boot starter xparent version 2.4.2

**Edit**:
The AllArgsConstructor is annotated by lombok.
I have the following properties:

```
@Value("${perscel.mail.featuretoggle}")
private final Boolean isFeatureActive;

@Value("#{'${perscel.mail.recipients.developers}'.split(',')}")
private final List<String> emailRecipientsDevelopers;

@Value("#{'${perscel.mail.recipients.admins}'.split(',')}")
private final List<String> emailRecipientsAdmins;
```

The two lists properly worked, I only have a problem after adding the boolean value.

Comment: This looks like Spring is trying to autowire a bean, not trying to resolve a `@Value` annotated field. Do you have a constructor ("Parameter 7 of constructor") with a `Boolean` parameter that you expected to use to initialize this field? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, they are being autowired, but it should be possible through dependency injection. The same was done through 2 other SPEL injections from the yaml file (list of strings); they didn't cause a problem. I'll look further into it.

Comment: If you're expecting constructor injection for the property value, your parameter needs to be annotated with `@Value`, not the field. If left un-annotated, Spring assumes it's `@Autowired`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added an edit. I will continue to look for a bit, but will provide a minimal example on Github if I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Spring complains on the constructor, not on the field annotation. So, this is basically because of missing `@Value` annotation on the constructor param in auto-generated code by Lombok.

You basically have 2 options:

1. Remove `@AllArgsConstructor` (and `final` field modifier), mark all
   the bean fields with `@Autowired` and let Spring *set* fields for
   you directly instead of using constructor.
2. Add constructor with all the arguments explicitly, not relying on
   Lombok auto-generated one. But this time - place `@Value` annotation
   on the corresponding constructor param.

Comment: This solution works, although I didn't get to get into why the constructor injection failed. Doesn't matter, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are marked all the `@Value` fields as `final`. Then what happens is `Lombok` will add those field to the constructor because you have annotated with `@AllArgsConstructor`.

When `Spring` initialize this bean, `Spring` assumes the all the filed in the constructor are `Spring` managed beans and `Spring` try to `autowire` them to this bean.

The easy fix is remove all the `final` word from those fields and remove `@AllArgsConstructor`. Removing `@AllArgsConstructor` always safe unless you are completely aware what is actually doing inside a `Spring` bean.

Comment: The two lists worked properly, so I don't see why it would be different for the Boolean object.